# MySQL primary key that I never select

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, primary-key

Quite often I encounter situation like this:

```
table `user_adress`
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+
|adress_id | user_id     | adress_type  |adress   |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+
|        1 |           1 | home         |adressXXX|
|        2 |           2 | home         |adressXXX|
|        3 |           3 | home         |adressXXX|
|        4 |           1 | work         |adressXXX|
|        5 |           2 | work         |adressXXX|
|        6 |           1 | second_home  |adressXXX|
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

If I want to use it, I'm using queries like this:

```
SELECT `adress` FROM `user_adress` WHERE `user_id`=1;
```

Seems quite normal, but the thing is, that I use "useless" `adress_id` column, that has no other purpouse but to be an primary key with autoincrement just for the sake of having an primary key in MySQL table. I never use or need this number. So I figured out that I should not use primary key in my table at all, remove totally `adress_id`, and set `INDEX` (without `unique`) at `user_id` column. That seems to be good - or am I wrong?

I have some doubts, because as much as I'm reading, everywhere I see advices, that every table should, or even need to have primary key. But why? Perhaps my database is badly designed if I allowed this to happen, but looking on my extreamly simple example table - I can't imagine how this could be the case in every situation, especially in such simple cases. I deffinetly missunderstanded some simple, basic rules about creating tables and properly indexing them - where is the hole in my toughts?

Comment: How would you delete user 1's home address without removing their work and second_home addresses? Even if you have a plan for that, some frameworks/environments cannot operate to their full capacity if their presumption of a primary key is not met.

Comment: You are absolutly right, I expanded the example table - my mistake!

Comment: `user_id, address_type` could be seen as a candidate primary key, but if someone had three home addresses you would have to add a new address type. Either way, you'd still end up with a primary key; it's just with the composite one, anything that references the address (perhaps a bill or ship to address) will now have to be joined/queried on two values instead of one.

Comment: Of note: There may be major performance impacts with InnoDB when using a non-incrementing primary key (or no primary key): http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/ Some replication systems like Galera need one, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz - That links to a bad test.  None of hist tables had a `PRIMARY KEY`, which is essential to InnoDB.  And the graphs head for the sky too fast.  And he did not say what value was used for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  But the conclusion is somewhat correct:  UUIDs suck for performance, in some situations.

Comment: @Zorann - The table name (user_address) implies that it might be a "many-to-many mapping table.  But the discussion sounds like it is not.  What is the case?

Comment: @Rick what do You mean by "many-to-many"? What's wrong with such table?

Comment: @RickJames You should probably reread that article. Each table's schema includes `primary key (id)`. The article also indicates he tinkered with `innodb_buffer_pool_size` as part of the experiment. "What I found is that increasing the buffers (specifically innodb_buffer_pool_size) did make a difference, but only for a brief period of time."

Comment: @ceejayoz - Ah yes, I was focusing on the 3 tables in the middle of the document.  Increasing the buffer_pool helps _until the uuid index is too big to be cached_.  This is because the processing is moving from CPU-bound to I/O-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely based on your table structure, I would say that your primary key is incorrect.

Instead, it looks like your primary should be:

```
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, address_type)
```

You are correct that every table should have a primary key ideally, but primary keys can be over *multiple* fields.

It is still sometimes easier to have a simple auto-incrementing id as your primary key. The Innodb storage engine will actually do this secretly in an invisible field.

Maybe in your limited example it's not needed, but in a lot of real-world cases it can just make it easier to work with the data. In that sense I would say that having an artificial auto-incrementing primary key is not a best practice from an academic standpoint, but it can be good idea from a 'real world, operational, and MySQL admin' perspective.

There's also ORM systems out there that simply require this (bad as that is).

Comment: I guess that You are right. I edited my example table - it's still fictional, but it does represent what I do have in my database, and now Your suggestion to use PK on user_id and adress_type(name changed) does have a lot of sense. The things that You are saying that such, as I called before, "useless" PK table is indeed used in background is quite interesting. Will this in fact work in my example, or should I add `INDEX` on `user_id` column? Or should I have both? Can I overextend the usage of pure, non-unique INDEX columns if i know that I'll often use it in my WHERE parts of queries?

Comment: @Zorann I changed my PRIMARY KEY to match your new field type. You still don't need an artificial PK, but in your case it does still make sense to have a PK over both user_id and address_type. If you have that, you don't need an INDEX on user_id as the PK will be used.

Answer (score 1):

As is evident in your data  the primary key   allow the access directly to a single row without any problem or ambiguity .. (expecially for delete or updated)

this is specifically the purpose of a primary key  ..

di the fact you could need  join this table to others table by user_id

and index  (not unique ) on user_id

```
create index  myidx on mytable(user_id)
```

is really useful  for faster join  allow a direct access only at the rows related  to a single user_id

Answer (score 1):

It's true that a relational database table needs a primary key.

But it all comes down to the definition of a primary key. A primary key is NOT necessarily a single integer column that auto-increments.

A primary key is any column or set of multiple columns that can uniquely identify every row. In your case, the combination of `user_id` and `address_type` can do this (as Evert posted already).

So if you make your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_address (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  address_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  address TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, address_type)
);
```

Then you can update or delete one specific row at a time like this:

```
UPDATE user_address SET ...
WHERE user_id = ? AND address_type = ?;
```

Some people feel that it's more convenient to enforce a convention that every table should have a single integer column as its primary key. They even may insist that the column must be called `id` for the sake of consistency.

There's some advantage in consistency, but on the other hand, it's kind of brainless to insist on that convention even when it's not helpful.